# How to get something useful from this ANR log

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-anr-dialog

I'm struggling with ANRs for a few weeks now but I still feel blind with logs like [this](https://gist.github.com/semanticer/cc03c77fa459d6d898f6b10fb682edb0). It is too long for stackoverflow and I have no idea which part might be useful. 
It happens usually during initial synchronization when there is a ton of network request being processed in the background (and I'm almost 100% sure non of that is in the main thread) and I'm also making a lot of UI stuff like populating recyclerviews from shared preferences via RxJava observables so I'm observing a massive changes in SharedPreferences and using [sample](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html) method to handle possible back pressure. Thanks for any tips, I'm totally lost.

Comment: This log is murder. My eyes started bleeding at nearly half of it, and CTRL+F says there's no `exception` anywhere... Did you deploy the app? I had a crash log sent to me from my app and the log was pretty straight forwards like "Null Pointer Exception at line 20123 you stupid dumbass" and I fixed it :D

Comment: Is this your app? cz.vcelka.androidapp?

Comment: @GuilhermeP yes that's my package name

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have thread dumps for multiple processes in there. To get to the useful part, you can search for "Cmd line" until you find your process ("cz.vcelka.androidapp", the pid was 21574).

If you get an ANR that means that your main thread is blocked somehow, so you should look at its stack trace. Here it is :

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x74bc2fa0 self=0xb4db6500
  | sysTid=21574 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6fc1b34
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=785 stm=88 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe29a000-0xbe29c000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x05853836> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
  - locked <0x05853836> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:810)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:971)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1278)
  at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:203)
  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl$1.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:366)
  at android.app.QueuedWork.waitToFinish(QueuedWork.java:88)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3560)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java:-1)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

So your main thread is blocked waiting on a `CountDownLatch` inside `SharedPreferences` code. We can look at the source code of SharedPreferences to find out more. At some point when you called [SharedPreferences.Editor.apply()](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/6fb921a61b0ca6bac8002e0fdbeb521453dce408/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#L361), the `SharedPreferences` code enqueued the write to disk to a worker thread. It also called [QueuedWork.add(awaitCommit)](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/6fb921a61b0ca6bac8002e0fdbeb521453dce408/core/java/android/app/QueuedWork.java#L69), where `awaitCommit` is a `Runnable` that waits on the write operation (by means of `CountDownLatch`), and `QueuedWork.add()` is a method that enqueues work to be done *on the main thread* when the activity's `onPause` method is called. That is what happened : `onPause` was called, and now the main thread is stuck waiting on the worker thread to complete its write operation.

Now the problem is that the log you posted is incomplete. Several threads are missing, including the worker thread that never called `CountDownLatch.countDown()`, so it is not possible to tell what is causing the deadlock. If you post the whole log (for your process, I don't think the other ones are going to be useful), we can probably help more.

Edit : I noticed that [someone else here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905415/how-to-analyze-anr-in-sharedpreferences) ran into the same problem. For them, the worker thread was stuck in `fsync(2)`. `fsync` can be really slow (as in multiple seconds) if the file is big and / or the disk is busy. I suppose that could be causing the ANR. I'm not sure if that would classify as a bug in `SharedPreferences`... Seems a bit weird to trigger possibly long blocking operations on the main thread, even if called from `onPause`... If this is indeed your problem, the only workaround I can think of would be to use `commit()` instead of `apply()`, since that will do the write synchronously. You should do it from a background thread, given that in your particular setup it seems that it can take a pretty long time to flush to disk !

Or maybe your `SharedPreferences` file is just way too big, in which case you could try slimming it down (by using a database for instance).

Comment: Thanks! Sounds promising, I will further investigate this path and get back with an update. Google play developer console trims the log like this for some reason, any tips how to get it complete?

Comment: Also, I'm using [prefser](https://github.com/pwittchen/prefser) library for sharedPreferences write and observe so there is huge gson serialization/deserialization

Comment: So it looks like the move from `apply()` to `commit()` really significantly improved the situation since I already called this in background thread. I can still get ARN when I try very very hard but I guess next logical move now is to ease the work for `SharedPreferences`.